# TokenMismatchException após qualquer erro de ajax no Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

Estou trabalhando com o Laravel a pouco tempo e estou tendo um problema quando faço uso de requisições ajax. Quando minha aplicação retorna qualquer erro e eu tento enviar mais uma requisição, o Laravel me envia este erro:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:
```

Se eu atualizo a página (com o erro do meu código corrigido), ele não envia mais esta mensagem. Pode ser qualquer erro do lado do servidor como falta de variável, ortografia, arquivos, qualquer coisa, que na próxima requisição independente da rota que eu pegue ele irá retornar o erro acima.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que você pode solucionar isso da seguinte forma:

- Exibir o token em algum atributo de um elemento do DOM
- Capturar esse valor do token do DOM em cada requisição ajax e enviá-lo como o valor `_token`.

Então, poderia ser feito mais ou menos assim:

```
<body data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}"></body>
```

No ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {..., _token: $('body').data('token') }
});
```

Outra forma de configurar as suas requisições ajax (e creio que seja a mais viável) é utilizando a função `$.ajaxSetup`, para que todas requisições herdem o header com o token. Assim:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('body').data('token')
        }
  });
```

No arquivo `VerifyCsrfToken.php`, você terá de adicionar esse método:

```
protected function tokensMatch($request)
{

    if ($request->ajax()) {

       $token = $request->input('_token');

    } else {

       $token = $request->header('X-CSRF-Token');

    }

    return $request->session()->token() == $token;
}
```

## Desabilitando o Token

Se quiser desabilitar a verificação de token em requisições ajax (o que não considero nada seguro), você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
protected function tokensMatch($request)
{

    if ($request->ajax()) return true;        

    return $request->session()->token() == $token;
}
```

Comment: Sempre que eu peço um AJAX eu já envio um elemento `{_token:token}` portanto este não seria o erro. Se eu coloco a 1ª versão da função no arquivo ele nem aceita a primeira requisição e a 2ª versão é totalmente inviável porque sai da lógica de segurança CSRF-Token

Comment: @LeandroLUK, você vai ter que dar um refresh no token então, hein!

Comment: Como que eu posso fazer o esse refresh? Porque a página não foi recarregada, portanto não há como fazer essa requisição... a não ser que eu crie um método somente para "chamar o token novo" e atualizar a variável se precisar

Comment: Estranho @LeandroLUK é que estou vendo vários posts que foram dados como resolvidos da forma que eu fiz.

Comment: @LeandroLUK, pela lógica, realmente o token deve atualizar de tempo em tempo. Mas isso não significa que  ele atualize a cada requisição. Talvez seja outra fator que esteja influenciando no erro

Comment: @LeandroLUK,mas você tem que editar a classe referente ao token. Não é simplesmente colocar o token na requisição ajax (no caso de definir o token como parâmetro da requisição).  E você também poderia set o header do token pelo jQuery, pra não ter também que colocar o token toda hora.

Comment: Então você acha que o melhor método seria eu gerando um vetor para recuperar este token (de tempos em tempos) e atualizar minha página?

Comment: Definitivamente não @LeandroLUK. Seu código está em algum respositório git ou algo assim? Eu gostaria de dar uma olhada mais a fundo :)

Answer (score 3):

Apenas complementando a resposta do @Wallace Maxters.

Caso não haja necessidade de utilizar a proteção de CSRF em nenhum lugar do projeto, é possível desabilitar  essa opção por completo alterando o arquivo `app/Http/Kernel.php` e removendo o middleware `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken`

Lembrando que fazendo isso você não estará mais protegido contra CSRF, caso seja necessário manter a resposta do @Wallace Maxters é a mais indicada.

Mais informações:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-avoiding-csrf-middleware-on-api-post-routes

Comment: sim já tinha conhecimento sobre isso. na documentação do Laravel tem essa informação.